# Can Jenkins multibranch plugin launch a script/event/job after branch deletion?

Tags: git, jenkins

I want trigger some actions when a branch is removed from GIT repository using jenkins multibranch plugin. Do you know if exists any way to trigger an event (like launch a specific job or a script) when a branch has been deleted?,

As an example, we are deploying some artifacts on remote repository with the branch as a label, if the branch disappear we want mark those artifacts to be deleted. (This is one of the task we want do, not the only one)

We have planned to do it using different approaches but if jenkins already can do it as part of the workflow using any pluggin.